# Change column datatypes in Hive database

Tags: database, sql, hadoop, apache-hive

Can I change the datatype in Hive database? Below is a complete information about the same.

I have a database named "test". It has a table "name". Below is a query I had used while creating a column in name table.

```
create table name(custID String,nameValuePairs array<struct< key:String, value:String>>) row format delimited fields terminated by '/' collection items terminated by '|' map keys terminated by '=' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Now, I would like to change the datatype entry of column name "nameValuePairs".

Currently the column `nameValuePairs` has datatype `array<struct< key:String, value:String>>`.

Now I would like to change the datatype to `array<struct< something:somedatatype, value:String>>`.

Comment: Since this seems to be a sql question, see also dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following `ALTER TABLE` syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name newType
```

To break it down, you are:

- Making a change to the table: `ALTER TABLE`
- Defining what table you are changing: `table_name`
- Defining what column you will change: `CHANGE column_name`
- Defining the change (you can also change column_name hence the double mention): `column_name newType`